# How would I make these animations animate at different times?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a whack-a-mole game and this is what I have so far, I'm aware this is sloppy and probably isn't the easiest/smartest way to do this. What I need to know is how to get my animations to animate at separate times. This current code works to animate 9 different moles coming out of holes but I need them to animate at different times(so none of them will come up at the same time, or within a few milliseconds of eachother) My current code is

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
body, a, a:hover {cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-5/oth438.cur),
progress;}
</style>
<body background = "http://i52.tinypic.com/34e9ekj.jpg">
<b><center><font size="5"><div id='counter'>0</div></font></center><b>
<b><center><i>Whack-A-Mole</i> - by Steven</center></b>
<div
   style="
      top: 37;
      left: 350;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<center><img id='animation0' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/></center>
</div>
<div
   style="
      top: 37;
      left: 33;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<left><img id='animation1' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/></left>
</div>

<div
   style="
      top: 37;
      left: 700;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<right><img id='animation2' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/></right>
</div>
<div
   style="
      top: 200;
      left: 352;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<img id='animation3' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>
</div>
<div
   style="
      top: 200;
      left: 33;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<img id='animation4' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>
</div>
<div
   style="
      top: 200;
      left: 700;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<img id='animation5' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>
</div>
<div
   style="
      top: 350;
      left: 700;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<img id='animation6' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>
</div>
<div
   style="
      top: 350;
      left: 33;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<img id='animation7' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>

</div>
<div
   style="
      top: 350;
      left: 352;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<img id='animation8' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>
</div>
</body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls;

function animate0(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation0 = document.getElementById('animation0');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation0.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation0.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation0.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate0(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate1(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation1 = document.getElementById('animation1');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation1.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation1.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation1.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate1(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate2(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation2 = document.getElementById('animation2');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation2.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation2.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation2.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate2(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate3(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation3 = document.getElementById('animation3');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation3.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation3.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation3.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate3(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate4(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation4 = document.getElementById('animation4');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation4.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation4.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation4.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate4(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate5(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation5 = document.getElementById('animation5');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation5.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation5.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation5.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing onclick
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate5(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate6(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation6 = document.getElementById('animation6');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation6.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation6.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation6.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate6(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate7(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation7 = document.getElementById('animation7');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation7.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation7.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation7.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate7(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
function animate8(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation8 = document.getElementById('animation8');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation8.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) { // only make onclick when have a certain image
        animation8.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation8.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
       setTimeout(function() {
        animate8(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
window.onload = function() { //Frames go below, seperated by commas format= , "URL");
    urls = new Array("http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif", "http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif");
    animate0(0);
    animate1(0);
    animate2(0);
    animate3(0);
    animate4(0);
    animate5(0);
    animate6(0);
    animate7(0);
    animate8(0);
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Little of both, ahahah..Idk, I just figured it would be a nice, difficult beginning project for javascript. :P

Comment: This is going to asplode in IE haha

Answer (score 1):

Generate 9 random numbers between 0 and your start time variation.  Decide the max distance you want between the animations and scale the random numbers to that time frame.  Then, set 9 timers to those times from now so each timer starts an animation.

If you wanted the animations to start over 500 milliseconds, you'd do something like this:

```
var randomTimes = [9];

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    randomTimes[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
}
```

Now you have 9 random times spread out over 500 milliseconds and you can use those values with setTimeout to start each animation at a random time.

Comment: I see what your saying, but it's not a .gif animation, I was saving the frames as .gifs because of the other formats lack of support for transparent backgrounds. I actually use a url array, with two frames for the animation. While this would be great if I had only one frame(a .gif animation) I have two frames.

Comment: Well, technically you're spreading out over 499 ms, but I won't dock you for that ;)

Comment: @Steven.  OK, however the animations work, you can use the random numbers to start each of your animations at different times.  You will probably end up wanting to use some more random numbers to control/manage your animations too (variable time up/down and then how long until it repeats).

Answer (score 0):

Copy/pasting a function this way is indeed sloppy!

You need to setup a flag:

```
var isMole  = false;//at first there is no mole
if(!isMole){    
   //there is no mole, you can show one here    
   isMole = true;//there is a mole now!
}else{
   //there is a mole, we wait.
}
```

Now set that flag to false when the mole times out or it struck by a hammer!

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how I'd integrate this into the current function. (I'm a noob with javascript :P) It makes sense, but I don't see how to implement it..Could you show me how to implement it into my function or into whatever function you see fit? ahah, thanks.